# Roslyn CSharpSyntaxRewriter Get A List of Implemented Interfaces

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have a CustomRewriter implementing CSharpSyntaxRewriter.  Within either the VisitClassDeclaration or VisitMethodDeclaration I need to check for ANY Interfaces that the class might implement.

The reason is that VisitMethodDeclaration is looking for methods that make data calls and is adding a parameter to the method.  This is working.  However, if modifies a method signature I need it to check if the Method altered comes from an implemented interface and if it does then modify the Interface as well.

I cannot figure out a way to get this information from Class & Method DeclarationNode parms nor the Syntax Tree or Syntax Nodes.  I also added Compilation as a Constructor Parm in an effort to use it to get the SchematicModel and somehow go from there, but without any luck.

```
public class DetermineIfInterfaceMethodRewriter : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    private string Test = string.Empty;
    private Compilation comp;
    public DetermineIfInterfaceMethodRewriter(Compilation compilation)
    {
        this.comp = compilation;
    }
    public override SyntaxNode VisitClassDeclaration(ClassDeclarationSyntax node)
    {  
        return base.VisitClassDeclaration(node);
    }
    public override SyntaxNode VisitMethodDeclaration(MethodDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        var tree = node.SyntaxTree;
        var root = tree.GetRoot();

        return node;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This information is available from the `INamedTypedSymbol` for the Class which can be obtained through the `SemanticModel GetDeclaredSymbol` Method.  Once you have the Symbol for the Class you can call `AllInterfaces` to get a collection of implemented interfaces.

```
    public override SyntaxNode VisitClassDeclaration(ClassDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        var tree = node.SyntaxTree;
        var root = tree.GetRoot();            
        var sModel = comp.GetSemanticModel(node.SyntaxTree);
        var classSymbol = sModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(root.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().First());

        var implementedInterfaces = classSymbol.AllInterfaces;

        return base.VisitClassDeclaration(node);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the semantic model:

1. Call `GetDeclaredSymbol(classDeclarationSyntax)` to get the `ITypeSymbol` for the class.
2. Call [`AllInterfaces`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/ITypeSymbol.cs,46) to get all of its implemented interfaces.

Comment: I'm missing something here though.  Calling.GetType off of the SemanticModel doesn't take any parms, its just the standard GetType off of Object.  I thought maybe you meant .GetTypeInfo(node) which gives you a TypeInfo Object but that doesn't have any "AllInterfaces" method?

Comment: I thought maybe you were referring to .GetSymbolInfo off of scemanticmodel but that only returns a SymbolInfo and not an ITypeSymbol.

Comment: I found it, its GetDeclaredSymbol off of semantic model:

var classSymbol = sModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(root.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().First());