# SourceGenerator Get all classes which implement an interface decorated by an attribute

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, sourcegenerators

I am trying to create a source generator for some automationg purpose. My target types are some classes which implement unknown interfaces. Those interfaces are decorated with a custom attribute. By searching everywhere, I can only find samples where people have attributes directly on target type, which unfortunately does not work in this case.

Here's that sample target code:

```cs
public sealed class SomeAttribute : Attribute
{

}

[Some]
public interface IA
{

}

internal sealed class A : IA
{

}
```

But in source generator `ClassDeclarationSyntax` does not seems to provide interfaces, instead I can only get attributes. This answer given here [Roslyn CSharpSyntaxRewriter Get A List of Implemented Interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49159819/roslyn-csharpsyntaxrewriter-get-a-list-of-implemented-interfaces/49161328#49161328) says that we can do following:

```cs
var root = classDeclarationSyntax.SyntaxTree.GetRoot();
var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(root.SyntaxTree);
ISymbol? symbol = model.GetDeclaredSymbol(root.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().First())

var implementedInterfaces = symbol.AllInterfaces;
```

But this does not work for me as `symbol` does not contain `AllInterfaces` property. My question how can I get interface list from `ClassDeclarationSyntax`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

figured it out. We need to cast `symbol` to `ITypeSymbol` like below:

```cs
var interfaces = ((ITypeSymbol)symbol).AllInterfaces
```